# GetBasicPropertiesAsync throws InvalidOperationException in WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I'm using `GetBasicPropertiesAsync()` to calculate the available space on the phone (Windows Phone 8.1 RT application).

The method works fine, but sometimes it throws an `InvalidOperationException` causing the application to crash. I get the following stacktrace:

```
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: A method was called at an unexpected time. 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000000E), A method was called at an unexpected time.
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000000E), Message: A method was called at an unexpected time.
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000000E), Stacktrace:    
at Windows.Storage.StorageFolder.GetBasicPropertiesAsync()
```

I'm unable to find the cause for this exception. Can anyone give some pointers?